# Overloading operator [] for a sparse vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to create a "sparse" vector class in C++, like so:

```
template<typename V, V Default>
class SparseVector {
    ...
}
```

Internally, it will be represented by an `std::map<int, V>` (where `V` is the type of value stored). If an element is not present in the map, we will pretend that it is equal to the value `Default` from the template argument.

However, I'm having trouble overloading the subscript operator, `[]`. I must overload the `[]` operator, because I'm passing objects from this class into a Boost function that expects `[]` to work correctly.

The `const` version is simple enough: check whether the index is in the map, return its value if so, or `Default` otherwise.

However, the non-const version requires me to return a reference, and that's where I run into trouble. If the value is only being *read*, I do not need (nor want) to add anything to the map; but if it's being *written*, I possibly need to put a new entry into the map. The problem is that the overloaded `[]` does not know whether a value is being *read* or *written*. It merely returns a reference.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or perhaps to work around it?

Comment: boost::mapped_vector<> should do something similar - you can study it for ideas (or maybe just use it).

Comment: It doesn't support my Default values, and also, I was going to do this for a two-dimensional matrix, so using it directly is out of the question. But still a useful reference!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There may be some very simple trick, but otherwise I think `operator[]` only has to return something which can be assigned from V (and converted to V), not necessarily a V&. So I think you need to return some object with an overloaded `operator=(const V&)`, which creates the entry in your sparse container.

You will have to check what the Boost function does with its template parameter, though - a user-defined conversion to V affects what conversion chains are possible, for example by preventing there being any more user-defined conversions in the same chain.

Comment: This is the only solution. On the other hand, proxy objects aren't perfect either - for example, if `V` had any overloaded conversion operators, a proxy won't be able to seamlessly propagate them.

Comment: Ah just tested the boost vectors. Looks like they behave this way too. Interesting.

Comment: (And `vector<bool>` isn't an STL container either.)

Comment: For the use of the boost algorithm it is probably okay, however if one would expect to catch the result with a temporary variable (say a V&) what happens ?

Comment: Um, without testing it I'd say compilation failure (if the reference is non-const), or a temporary bound to the variable (if the reference is const). `operator[]` is optional in the Sequence interface (23.1.1). This container doesn't implement it as defined in that table (returning an lvalue of T and taking amortized constant time as specified in table 68 and clause 12 respectively): algorithms which take iterators only require that `operator*` be assignable from T, not that it return `T&`, and I'm expecting/hoping that the same is true of this unspecified Boost function which uses [] instead.

Answer (score 9):

Don't let the non-const operator& implementation return a reference, but a proxy object. You can then implement the assignment operator of the proxy object to distinguish read accesses to operator[] from write accesses.

Here's some code sketch to illustrate the idea. This approach is not pretty, but well - this is C++. C++ programmers don't waste time competing in beauty contests (they wouldn't stand a chance either). ;-)

```
template <typename V, V Default>
ProxyObject SparseVector::operator[]( int i ) {
   // At this point, we don't know whether operator[] was called, so we return
   // a proxy object and defer the decision until later
   return ProxyObject<V, Default>( this, i );
}

template <typename V, V Default>
class ProxyObject {
    ProxyObject( SparseVector<V, Default> *v, int idx );
    ProxyObject<V, Default> &operator=( const V &v ) {
      // If we get here, we know that operator[] was called to perform a write access,
      // so we can insert an item in the vector if needed
    }

    operator V() {
      // If we get here, we know that operator[] was called to perform a read access,
      // so we can simply return the existing object
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to have a type be convertible to e.g. both a `const int &` and an `int &`, and have the compiler select the former whenever it can use a non-writable lvalue?  I'd like to have a proxy object return a reference to a field which is loaded form the main object, and then have its destructor copy the field back to the main object if it may have changed, but I can't figure out how to avoid the write-back on a read-only access.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether this design is sound.

If you want to return a reference, that means that clients of the class can store the result of calling `operator[]` in a reference, and read from/write to it at any later time. If you do not return a reference, and/or do not insert an element every time a specific index is addressed, how could they do this? (Also, I've got the feeling that the standard requires a proper STL container providing `operator[]` to have that operator return a reference, but I'm not sure of that.)

You might be able to circumvent that by giving your proxy also an `operator V&()` (which would create the entry and assign the default value), but I'm not sure this wouldn't just open another loop hole in some case I hadn't thought of yet.

`std::map` solves this problem by specifying that the non-const version of that operator always inserts an element (and not providing a `const` version at all).

Of course, you can always say this *is not* an off-the-shelf STL container, and `operator[]` does not return plain references users can store. And maybe that's OK. I just wonder.

Comment: About the soundness of the design: it's a memory optimization of a general vector, to be used in specific cases - so the interface/contract/documentation should cover that.  About the validity of references: even the stl iterators aren't always valid.

Comment: @xtofl: however, STL containers define very carefully what operations can invalidate iterators and/or references to elements of the container. This container should do the same, and users must ensure that any templates using the class as a parameter don't make demands that it can't satisfy.